# Add 3D visualizer in Ros-Qt project

Tags: ros, rviz, 3d-visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I m using ROS noetic in Ubuntu 20.04 with Qt5. I m trying to develop a module to visualize point cloud data on a 3D visualizer. I noticed RViz utilises a 3D visualizer as highlighted in below image:
[image: #D Visualizer Window]

I m interested to integrate only that window in my Qt project. How can I include it?

I have worked earlier on similar project and used VTK library's 3D visualizer window plugin(QVTK Plugin) in Qt. Now I want to replace the VTK library dependency.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386398/add-3d-visualizer-in-ros-qt-project/) by [SurajJadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/71239/surajjadhav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2021-09-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-13**:
Have you checked this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0r4uKK1zkk?

**Comment by [SurajJadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/71239/surajjadhav/) on 2021-09-13**:
I m aware about the RViz's functionality and visualizing camera and point cloud data in it, I m trying to develop a Qt application which has a point cloud data visualizer, I can use RViz as well but it has lot of other functions which are not required.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-13**:
in that case, RVIZ is also a library and it's open source: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz

Here is an example how to access some of the RVIZ functionality in C++: https://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/librviz_tutorial/html/index.html

and in Python: https://docs.ros.org/en/indigo/api/rviz_python_tutorial/html/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RVIZ is also a library and it's open source: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz

Here is an example how to access some of the RVIZ functionality in C++: https://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/librviz_tutorial/html/index.html

and in Python: https://docs.ros.org/en/indigo/api/rviz_python_tutorial/html/

More info:

http://wiki.ros.org/visualization_tutorials

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-15**:
I think that also can be helpful.
install visualization tutorials:

Follow of tutorial installation: `sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-visualization-tutorials`

Thanks,

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-15**:
100% agree.

**Comment by [SurajJadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/71239/surajjadhav/) on 2021-09-16**:
Thanks @Osilva and @Ranjit Kathiriya, I m going through the RViz project and it is huge, for now I m going to survey, what is this window they are using, how to extract only the visualization part from the code and its dependencies.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-16**:
Please vote to close the question, and you may ask future questions specific to using RVIZ. Cheers :)